# Check 30 minute interval pair and ignore if pair not found

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I'm expecting the following sequence of time data in 30 minute interval from another system. I need to make this 30 minute pair in to one hour interval:

e.g.
Source Data:

```
Start:7:00
End: 7:30
Start:7:30
End: 8:00
Start:8:00
End: 8:30
Start:8:30
End: 9:00
```

Convert in to hour data like below:

```
Start:7:00
End: 8:00
Start:8:00
End: 9:00
```

If there's no match for 30 minute block this record should be ignored:
e.g

```
 Start:7:00
    End: 7:30
    Start:7:30
    End: 8:00
    Start:8:00
    End: 8:30
    Start:8:30
    End: 9:00
    Start:9:00 <-- Ignore this 
    End: 9:30  <-- Ignore this
```

Can someone please suggest how this can be achieved?

Comment: What is your source data? A String, an object?

Comment: @msarchet, the source is List of object that contains start properties.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea for my solution is that you simply only take elements at indices:

> 0, 3, 4, 7, 8, 11, 12, ...

Or in other words - if `index % 4` is 0 or 3.

Before doing that, we check if there are leftover dates at the end with `count % 4`.
If there are - we cut them.

This assumes that the dates will be all valid as the input you illustrated.

Here is my implementation:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> CutTimes(IEnumerable<DateTime> source)
{
    var count = source.Count();
    var ignore = count % 4;

    if (ignore != 0)
    {
        source = source.Take(count - ignore);
    }

    return source.Where((time, index) => index % 4 == 0 || index % 4 == 3);
}
```

Usage:

```
var times = new[]
                {
                    new DateTime(2012, 5, 10, 7, 00, 0),
                    new DateTime(2012, 5, 10, 7, 30, 0),
                    new DateTime(2012, 5, 10, 7, 30, 0),
                    new DateTime(2012, 5, 10, 8, 00, 0),
                    new DateTime(2012, 5, 10, 8, 00, 0),
                    new DateTime(2012, 5, 10, 8, 30, 0),
                    new DateTime(2012, 5, 10, 8, 30, 0),
                    new DateTime(2012, 5, 10, 9, 00, 0),
                    new DateTime(2012, 5, 10, 9, 00, 0),
                    new DateTime(2012, 5, 10, 9, 30, 0)
                };

var result = CutTimes(times);

foreach (var time in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(time);
}
```

Output:

> 10/05/2012 07:00:00
>
> 10/05/2012 08:00:00
>
> 10/05/2012 08:00:00
>
> 10/05/2012 09:00:00